# What bare minimum kit do I need to become an airsoft skirmisher?

Tags: equipment, shooting, airsoft

If I wanted to get into airsoft as a player new to the sport, what would be the bare minimum kit I'd need to purchase before going to a game as a walk-on player that would ensure my weapon and I are permitted at any site worldwide?

Assume that kit includes everything from footwear to headgear, weapon(s), ammunition and anything in between.

I realise there are some differences in the law between various countries, and that generally the requirements can vary between sites (especially between *Close Quarters Battle* (CQB) and outdoor sites), so by *any site worldwide*, I'm interested in a baseline set of kit that would satisfy nearly all, or all skirmish sites (CQB or outdoor) in any country that permits airsofting.

Are there any recommended extras that would help, but are not required and what are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say the bare minimum is essential for anyone looking to get into airsoft - even if its just a one off day. Those essentials would be the following:

- Good pair of boots - this is a must and can easily turned a broken ankle into a sprain. I would always recommend that as someones first purchase, regardless of the terrain.
- Eye protection - sure you can rent from most reputable sites, but I would personally always buy my own, even if you start with a cheaper pair and upgrade as you become more experienced.
- Loose clothing that you don't mind getting destroyed - always start with loose clothing when first starting out as there is nothing worse than being hit on what might as well be bare skin (if the clothing is too tight on your body).

Thats about it in regards to essentials - I would recommend **not** looking into purchasing a weapon until you have at least tried it a few times. Pay the little bit extra on a gameday and use rentals as it will not only give you a real feel for it, but also give you experience with different weapons. Sidearms are also a luxury when you progress more into the sport.

As you gain more experience, you will naturally start to learn and get a feel for your own play-style and therefore be able to judge what kit/gear might work well for you.

Comment: Welcome to sports.SE! I hadn't considered that the weapon isn't essential, but looking back I didn't buy for a few games and all the sites I've been to offer rental packages. Thank you.